# how to display solidworks[sldprt,sldasm] file in webgl[threejs] and control it?

Tags: webgl, solidworks

My way of converting SolidWorks files to STL, and converts it to a obj,ThreeJS load.

However, this is too much trouble.

I want to show SolidWorks files directly into the ThreeJS [sldprt,sldasm] and control, like GrabCAD, but I don't know how to do it, someone here can help me? Thank you!

Comment: This is the same problem of me.